# Add a NSString to a .plist (property list) file

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I tried to read many questions/tutorials but i can't find the answer!
I'm trying to get a string from a textField and save it in a datas.plist file i created (under the default key Root)
i've tried this code:

```
//Save Name to plist
        if([name.text length] > 0){
            NSString *string = name.text;
            [array addObject:string];
            //plist path
            NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"datas" ofType:@"plist"];
            //save object
            [array writeToFile: path atomically:YES];

        }
```

where array is a

```
@interface DetailViewController (){
    NSMutableArray* array;
}
```

But the app crashes when i try to save (the action i wrote before is connected to a button) giving this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an
>   NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'

i think the code that writes is incorrect because i never type the key where to save (like @"Root") or something like that.
Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

i tried this code but doesn't write anything:

```
- (void)addToMyPlist {
    NSString *destPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    destPath = [destPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dati"];

    // If the file doesn't exist in the Documents Folder, copy it.
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:destPath]) {
        NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dati" ofType:@"plist"];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destPath error:nil];
    }

    // Load the Property List.
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:destPath];

        //NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dati" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSString *string = self.name.text;

        NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:string, nil];
        NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Root", nil];
        NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
        [array addObject:dict];
        [array writeToFile:destPath atomically:YES];
}
```

what's wrong?

Comment: If I got one cent every time this is asked on Stack Overflow...

Comment: Your plist problem and your exception (Core Data) would seem to be unrelated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the files in the bundle are read-only.

You'll have to move your pList in the private Documents (or another, there are 3 of them available) folder of your app to have write privilege.

For example, copy your bundle file in Documents directory :

```
if([name.text length] > 0){
        NSString *string = name.text;
        [array addObject:string];

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error;
        //Path to document directory
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        //Path to your datas.plist inside documents directory
        NSString *documentsPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"datas.plist"];

        //If the file doesn't exists yet
        if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentsPath] == NO) {
            //Let's copy it in your Documents folder
            NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"datas" ofType:@"plist"];

            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:documentsPath error:&error];
        }

        [array writeToFile: documentsPath atomically:YES];

    }
```

Comment: i created the plist file from Xcode newFile>.. and it was created in my app's folder by default i think

Comment: i tried replacing your code but it always gives me this error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'

Comment: @ObiWanKeNerd This error is linked to CoreData. If you don't use it, try to disable it, or remove Coredata init functions in the AppDelegate

Comment: i solved the Core Data problem, but pasting you code it still doesn't do anything. Plus i got this question if i right-click on the .plist field and click on Add Row nothing happens i still only have only the Key "Root" by default

Comment: @ObiWanKeNerd You might check that you have the write permission on your file (*cmd + i* in the Finder on your pList)